# Making pdf-tools work after successful compiling on mac os x

Tags: latex, auctex, preview-latex, pdf-tools

After installing the required dependencies with homebrew, I was able to compile pdf-tools . But I cannot make it work (I cannot see the pdf on emacs after compiling)

I would like to know if somebody can post its .emacs config to make pdf-tools work since I have not been able to make it happen. I have tried several options, like the following (copy from somebody else):

```
(load "pdf-tools") ;;
(setq output-pdf "PDF Tools") ;;          
(pdf-tools-install)                                                   
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-dvi "Okular")              
                                   (output-pdf "PDF Tools") ;;        
                                   ))
```

Or also

```
;; Use pdf-tools to open PDF files
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "PDF Tools"))
      TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)

;; Update PDF buffers after successful LaTeX runs
(add-hook 'TeX-after-TeX-LaTeX-command-finished-hook
           #'TeX-revert-document-buffer)
```

But, after compiling a tex file (with C-c C-c with Auctex) and trying to see the pdf with the same command (and selecting View), I always get the error

```
Unknown PDF Tools viewer. Check the Tex-view-program-selection variable
```

I am sure I am missing a key config for making pdf-tools available or known to auctex/emacs, but cannot figure it out. Could you please post your config to get an inspiration from it? I have already checked [install-pdf-tools-on-emacs-macosx](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13314/install-pdf-tools-on-emacs-macosx/21109?noredirect=1#comment32647_21109), [how-to-let-auctex-open-pdf-with-pdf-tools](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19472/how-to-let-auctex-open-pdf-with-pdf-tools) and [how-to-use-pdf-tools-pdf-view-mode-in-emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19686/how-to-use-pdf-tools-pdf-view-mode-in-emacs) without success.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Making already visited links more explicit.

Comment: Does the following link resolve your issue?:  **How to let AUCTeX open PDF with pdf-tools**: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19475/2287

Comment: Hi, that is the second link I put in my question and still it does not work and shows me the same error.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I don't usually click on something that says "this".  My bad . . . please disregard then.

Comment: Do not worry. I have edited the question to make links more clear.

Comment: What version of AUCTeX do you have?  Support for PDF Tools has been introduced in 11.89.

Comment: Hi, I have AUCTeX 11.89.1 but still pdf-tools does not work. Now it is working with AUCTeX 11.89.4

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to add "PDF Tools" to the list of available PDF Tools. This must happen automagically for some people (or there would be more complaints about this on stackexchange!), but apparently not for you or me.

Here is my config:

```lisp
(pdf-tools-install) ;; start server
(load "pdf-tools") ;; not clear if this is needed.

;; add "PDF Tools" to the list of possible PDF tools
(unless (assoc "PDF Tools" TeX-view-program-list
  (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-list
           '("PDF Tools" TeX-pdf-tools-sync-view)))
(add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-selection
          '(output-pdf "PDF Tools"))

(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "PDF Tools")))

;; Update PDF buffers after successful LaTeX runs
(add-hook 'TeX-after-TeX-LaTeX-command-finished-hook
         'TeX-revert-document-buffer)
```

Comment: The "magic" to make PDF Tools appear is to upgrade to AUCTeX 11.89 and don't fiddle with `TeX-view-program-list-builtin`.  The variable intended to be customized by the users is `TeX-view-program-list`.

Comment: "builtin" was a type-o. Thanks for fixing that. Merely updated to auctex 11.89 alone is not enough, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you mean that in AUCTeX 11.89 you don't have the `"PDF Tools"` entry for `TeX-view-program-list-builtin`?

Comment: I have updated AUCTex from 11.89.1 to 11.89.4, also installed the latest version for pdf-tools, and it is working correctly.

Comment: I have AUCTex 11.89.4. TeX-view-program-list-builtin does not include "PDF Tools".

Comment: @iluvatar - did you need to use the setup I described above? Or did it just work for you out of the box?

Comment: @user3291354 Surprisingly, with the Auctex version I mentioned, it worked without any additional configuration. I just needed to run first pdf-tools-install and also link epdfinfo from /usr/local/bin to /usr/bin

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your auctex is up-to-date and that you followed the instructions for installing the package, including the `M-x package-install-file RET pdf-tools-${VERSION}.tar RET` step, all you should need is

```el
;; Initialize the package (this should autoload it too)
(pdf-tools-install)
;; Select PDF Tools as your viewer for PDF files
(setcdr (assq 'output-pdf TeX-view-program-selection) '("PDF Tools"))
;; If you want synctex support, this should be sufficient assuming 
;; you are using LaTeX-mode
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-source-correlate-mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered this here: [Install Pdf-Tools on Emacs MacOSX](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13314/install-pdf-tools-on-emacs-macosx)

You'll also find this helpful for application/mode/package specific tweaks: [How to use pdf-tools (pdf-view-mode) in emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19686/how-to-use-pdf-tools-pdf-view-mode-in-emacs)